Why is the NFL season called 2024, not 2024-25?
According to NFL.com stats section, NFL seasons are called 2024, 2023, 2022, and so on, not 2024-25, 2023-24, 2022-23, and so on. I wonder why they call the seasons so even though the last game of the regular season is held in January of the next year and all post season game including the most important Super Bowl is held in the next year.
Is there any specific reason for this?

I mean, there hasn't been a reason to call seasons that way until recently, and tradition/laziness is strong. And it's not like half of the regular season is in the next year like the NBA and NHL
